# GVIM Syntax for CV2

Tags: vim, computer-vision, opencv3.0, opencv, python

I cant figure out how to highlight cv2 syntaxs, or any CV based syntaxs in gvim. any help? Im able to highlight python and other langs, but for computer vision am having trouble. this is in ubuntu 16.04lts

Comment: What do you mean by "cv2 syntax" ? Is this about opencv ? Usually syntax highlighting depends only on the language used which, for opencv, can be C++, Python and more.

Comment: If you're using `cv2`, the syntax you want to tell the editor you're using is `python`